Bitbucket Data Center in Kubernetes - shared home not writeable, mounted volume owner is root
I'm setting up Bitbucket data center on minikube and I have following problem when mounting volume:
The following problems occurred, which prevents Atlassian Bitbucket from starting:      Bitbucket Shared Home [/var/atlassian/application-data/bitbucket/shared] exists but is not writable by Bitbucket     SpringMVC dispatcher [springMvc] could not be started 

I checked and while /var/atlassian/application-data/bitbucket is owned by bitbucket, /var/atlassian/application-data/bitbucket/shared is owned by root.
As i checked in logs - bitbucket tries to create this directory after pod is created, then it starts setup and creation of external database, then it fails due to the fact that it can't access this directory.
Here is my .yaml of deployment:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: bitb
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: bitb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: bitb
    spec:
     containers:
        - name: bitb
          image: atlassian/bitbucket:8.16.4
          volumeMounts:
            - name: bitb-storage
              mountPath: "/var/atlassian/application-data/bitbucket"
          volumeMounts:
            - name: bitb-properties
              mountPath: "/var/atlassian/application-data/bitbucket/shared/bitbucket.properties"
              subPath: "bitbucket.properties"
          env:
            - name: BITBUCKET_HOME
              value: "/var/atlassian/application-data/bitbucket"
     volumes:
      - name: bitb-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: bitb
      - name: bitb-properties
        configMap:
          name: properties

bitbucket.properties needs to be mounted as volume, because i want to make sure that deployment will fix itself, so manually changing /shared directory owner with kubectl exec is not an option.
I tried to use init container to change owner but bitbucket user don't exist while init container is working.

The issue is definitely about directory permissions as the /var/atlassian/application-data/bitbucket/shared is owned by root. Whereas in deployment you are using a non root user. As you already tried to change the permissions with init container but facing difficulty.
So you can use the Securitycontext in deployment to run as root user. By using the correct runAsUser ((UID) and fsGroup (GID) you can run as root user so that the data can be written to /var/atlassian/application-data/bitbucket/shared directory.
Looks like there are some syntax errors in your deployment yaml like you don't need to keep volumeMount field 2 times. Below giving you the corrected yaml file along with the securitycontext changes.
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: bitb
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: bitb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: bitb
    spec:
     containers:
        - name: bitb
          image: atlassian/bitbucket:8.16.4
          securityContext:
           runAsUser: 1000  # Change to appropriate UID if different
           fsGroup: 1000  # Change to appropriate GID if different
          volumeMounts:
            - name: bitb-storage
              mountPath: "/var/atlassian/application-data/bitbucket"
            - name: bitb-properties
              mountPath: "/var/atlassian/application-data/bitbucket/shared/bitbucket.properties"
              subPath: "bitbucket.properties"
          env:
            - name: BITBUCKET_HOME
              value: "/var/atlassian/application-data/bitbucket"
     volumes:
      - name: bitb-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: bitb
      - name: bitb-properties
        configMap:
          name: properties

Refer this k8’s Securitycontext documentation for more information on permissions of contianers.
Check this document for more similar errors in Bitbucket.
Update:
Try using the labeldrop multiple times like below
    - action: labeldrop
      regex: feature_node_kubernetes_io_.*
    - action: labeldrop
      regex: nvidia_com_.*

